# Bottom of ConstraintLayout activity not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have layout files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar_activity_pool"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/logo_24dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_activity_inspection_details" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and @layout/content_activity_inspection_details:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/b_navigate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Navigate"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In activity I have:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspection_details);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.topAppBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

In Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".view.activity.InspectionDetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

**Problem:** is that `tv_name` is not visible - it is under toolbar.

I can add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` which is `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior` and that results in that `tv_name` is visible but the `button` is not then.

What should I change to have my `ConstraintLayout` starting below a toolbar and ending at the bottom of a screen?

Comment: You can add: app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_name" to the bottom for example

Comment: @Daan I would like to hava a botton at the bottom of the screen.
The easiest way is to add to the button  android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" but that is kind a hack. I'm sure there is correct way to achieve what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `exitUntilCollapsed` flag to the AppBarLayout flags

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

And add below behavoiur to the layout below the `AppBarLayout` which is the `ConstraintLayout`

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

So your layouts will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar_activity_pool"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/logo_24dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_activity_inspection_details" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**And @layout/content_activity_inspection_details:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/b_navigate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Navigate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```